# Achieving cyclic tile behavior with Flip tile.

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Currently I implemented my Flip Tile with the help of Scheduled Task, So one issue with similar approach is the Flip tile will flip the same image during the time interval. So what I am trying to achieve is I need to flip my images like cyclic tile. Ie one after another manner. One thing to notice here is I am using local (Isolated storage) images as Tile images not remote uri’s. Is it possible to achieve similar implementation in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the behaviour of the CycleTemplate then this is not possible with the FlipTemplate.

If you are trying to achieve having tiles which include a combination of images and text (set as Content in the FlipTemplate) then a solution would be to generate an image which includes the text you're interested in and then use that image, along with any other, in the CycleTemplate.

Comment: I am a bit confused: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx seems one can set BackBackgroundImage & BackContent in one go?